# String not being populated by edittext field. Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

There is probably a simple answer for this: when my alert box shows, I try to store the contents of a `EditText` in a string but, the string is always empty.

```
contents = inputElement.getText().toString();
```

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText inputElement;
Spinner spinner;
MySQLiteAdapters adapter; 
MySQLiteHelper helper_ob;
AlertDialog  dialog;
List<String> lables;
String contents;
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    //start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    inputElement = new EditText(this);
    adapter = new MySQLiteAdapters(getApplicationContext());
    lables = adapter.getAllLabels();
    exmaplePrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    editor = exmaplePrefs.edit();

    final AlertDialog firstTimeUse = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(inputElement)
            .setTitle("TITLE")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).create();

    firstTimeUse.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button b = firstTimeUse.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    contents = inputElement.getText().toString();
                    if (contents.matches("")){
                        showAlertbox("You Must Enter a Team");
                    }else{
                        adapter.insertTeamDetails(contents);
                        List<String> lables = adapter.getAllLabels();
                        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
                        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                        lables.add("Add New Team...");
                        firstTimeUse.dismiss();
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    });


    if (lables.isEmpty())
    {
        firstTimeUse.show();
    }
    else{
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        lables.add("Add New Team...");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new instance of `inputElement` in `onCreate`:

```
inputElement = new EditText(this);
```

So the text in it is always empty as you don't add it to the layout.

Instantiate it from the layout using `findViewById` or add it to the layout in the code.

Comment: does the .setView(inputElement) not add it to the AlertDialog?

Comment: I've never seen it used this way though. Usually you inflate a view that you add and find elements of the view. Like in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1):

`SetView(View view)` takes view element, I am not sure how you are adding EditText there. You can add edit text in layout file itself something like this:

and declare in onCreate something like this:

```
inputElement = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
```

You can get string like this:

```
inputElement.getText().toString();
```